# Adding Menu bar to QT cvNameWIndow

Tags: c++, c, qt, opencv, menubar

I am trying to create video-player application with open CV using QT creator. using openCV it is possible to play video files by adding each video frame as an image on an instance of cvNamedWindow.

Now I would like to add a menu bar to this cvNamedWindow so that I can add File, help etc menus. menus. I looked up the documentation of cvNamedWindow and I couldn't find any clue. Any suggestions?

P.s. In opencv windows created using QMainWindow, it is straightforwaed to add menu bar. But what I want is to add the menu bar to cvNamedWindow  not to a window created using QMainWindow.

Comment: OpenCV is ... well, Open. Get the source and add the feature. But are you sure you evaluated the task correctly ? What about timing ? And sound ?

Comment: @Dangila Check my answer when you can. I think it's exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV's [user interface](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) is quite limited, so there's no way to accomplish what you are looking for with OpenCV's API.

On the other hand, Qt has a rich API for building graphic applications. Luckily for you, I just shared **[cvVideo: an example that demonstrates how to play videos on a `QWidget` surface](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvVideo)**. Plus, the demo has some neat tricks to change [aspect ratio modes](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qt.html#AspectRatioMode-enum). Almost forgot, it displays a simple `QMenuBar` too.

Comment: @karlphilip, yes cvVideo is exactly what I am looking for. I cloned ur repo and after minor path corrections, I was able to run it. Unfortunately, the running window displays no menu bar at all. Any clues why this is happening? I am sorry if I am asking a vague question but since the projects runs with no error and warning, I couldn't figure out where to start.

Comment: I haven't tested this on Windows but it works perfectly on Mac OS X. I'll do that later if I have the time. But there are lot's of tutorials around that shows how to add a QMenuBar to an application, just google around. I believe the most complex part was done in cvVideo. Consider up voting my answer if it helped you or even marking it as the official answer to your question: you can do so by clicking on the checkbox near it. By doing these things you show that you understand how the forum works and you will be helping future visitors like yourself.

Comment: The latest commit of cvVideo fixed the issue you reported. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use createButton and createTrackbar with namedWindow, but that's it.

sure, you could simulate a menu with a row of buttons, but if you need something more advanced,
stick to the native Qt api.